# PHP/MySQL Security Can I mask the connection to the DB?

Tags: php, mysql, security

So, I have this site that I've been working on for a while - and I'm worried about security.

Essentially, I'd like to either MASK the connection to the database (if that's even possible) or create a connection class that I can reference when I need to connect to the database (or something better than I have now).

Currently, I'm using the `Require_Once` functionality to call the connection to the DB.

Is there a better, more secure way to do that?  I really don't like having the username, password and DB able to be read - if someone decided to go poking around.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Security is important to the site, since the users' information is stored in there (not just a hashed password, but BDay and other personal stuff, not SS#'s though.)

Comment: What do you mean by `mask`?

Comment: if there was some way to encrypt the connection - but Someone pointed out the answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the username, password and db connection **outside the public directory**:

```
/someweb
  /data
  /config <- db connection here
  /web <- web contents and document root here
```

If you set the /someweb/config access privileges to be accessible from Apache only (not from any user), it should be safe *"if someone decided to go poking around"*

If you are worried more (i.e. someone may get the someweb backup) you may **encrypt the /config contents** and decrypt it from some other place.

Comment: THAT!  That is beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to store the username, password, and database name somewhere; if a human can't read it or easily recover it, neither can your scripts. There's no point to trying to encrypt or disguise this information; anyone who can get at the encrypted/disguised version can also find your algorithm and/or keys for unlocking the plaintext version.

As Jan Turoň says, the best thing to do is put the information somewhere outside of your public directory.

You should also encrypt personal info like birthdays before storing it in the database. In that case, it is possible for someone to access the database but not the code, so encryption is actually useful.